# Colisiones en MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

En bases de datos relacionales como Oracle si estoy haciendo una transacción: ¿Esto tiene un backpoint, de tal manera que si hubo un problema los cambios no se realizan en la BD? ¿Se puede hacer esto de alguna manera en Mongo? ¿También existen transacciones en Mongo?

Answer (score 1):

En respuesta a tu pregunta y añadiendo un poco de teoría:

Las bases de datos relacionales suelen garantizar las propiedades de **ACID** relacionadas con la fiabilidad con la que se procesan las transacciones (tanto de lectura como de escritura). MySQL y PostgreSQL (entre muchas más) son ejemplos de bases de datos que proporcionan estas propiedades.

- La **atomicidad** requiere que cada transacción se ejecute en su
  totalidad o falle sin que se aplique ningún cambio.
- La **consistencia** requiere que la base de datos solo pase de un estado
  válido al siguiente, sin puntos intermedios.
- El **aislamiento** requiere que si las transacciones se ejecutan
  simultáneamente, el resultado sea equivalente a su ejecución en
  serie. Una transacción no puede ver el resultado parcial de la
  aplicación de otro.
- **Durabilidad** significa que el resultado de una transacción
  comprometida es permanente, incluso si la base de datos se bloquea
  inmediatamente o en caso de una pérdida de energía.

A lo que tu apuntas es como MongoDB maneja la atomicidad, para lo cual primero debería decirte que:

> En MongoDB, una operación de escritura es atómica en el nivel de un
>   solo documento, incluso si la operación modifica múltiples documentos
>   incrustados en un solo documento.
>
> Cuando una operación de escritura única modifica documentos múltiples,
>   la modificación de cada documento es atómica, pero la operación como
>   un todo no es atómica y otras operaciones pueden intercalarse.
>
> (Extraído de la documentación de MongoDB)

Por lo tanto, MongoDB proporciona solo una transacción en todo el documento: las escrituras nunca se aplican parcialmente a un documento insertado o actualizado. La operación es atómica en el sentido de que falla o tiene éxito, para el documento en su totalidad. **Para finalizar y resumir**, MongoDB si tiene "backpoint", solo guardara el dato, si la transacción fue exitosa, si hubo un error este volverá a su estado anterior (Backpoint).

Answer (score 0):

Hace poco anunciaron el roadmap para Mongodb 4.0 y 4.2 en el que incluyen **transacciones multidocumento** (sólo para *replicaSet* en 4.0 y también para *sharding* en la versión 4.2). tal cual lo hacen la bases relacionales (incluso con una sintaxis muy parecida)

Te dejo un par de links por si te interesa:

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/seminal-product-announcement-dev-ittycheria 
https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/multi-document-transactions-in-mongodb?jmp=community